# Why is the Fortran RANDOM_SEED input an array?

Tags: random, fortran, random-seed

I use the following code to initialise me seed (I don't know where I found it, but everyone, absolutely everyone seems to have exactly this! Why? Why 37?)

```
SUBROUTINE init_random_seed()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i, n, clock
INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: seed

CALL RANDOM_SEED(size = n)
ALLOCATE(seed(n))

CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(COUNT=clock)

seed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)
CALL RANDOM_SEED(PUT = seed)

DEALLOCATE(seed)
END SUBROUTINE
```

Now why is the argument of PUT an array (of size .ge. n)? I can only find sources that say that that is how it should be, not why.

1. Pg.12 of http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/general/chapman/intro/INTRINSI.PDF
2. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html
3. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581112

Comment: It's an array because the Fortran standard says it's an array (which could be of size 1).  Beyond that, are you asking why a PRNG may benefit from having a state described by more than one number?

Comment: Yes. In particular, the PRNG described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt *"absolutely everyone"* has your expression with 37.

Why 37? One can hypothesize it is because some pseudo random generators may give sequences of suspicious quality from trivial initial seeds (like [0,0,0...] + current_time) and so they chose some sufficiently large (but not too large to avoid overflow) prime number and use multiples of that one to get some more non-trivial seed. One can still argue whether there will be enough entropy in this seed and I would avoid this expression for advanced usage (cryptography or even some Monte-Carlo simulations).

To be sure you must ask those guys who came up with this particular expression.

Would other values like 31 or 41 work similarly? I very much believe so. You can try them and see, but you can expect different results from different compilers which use different generators. You can also use some other combination of even larger prime numbers and not just multiples of one of them, there are many possibilities...

If you want to get a different seed value each time, you can also use the method showed in the GCC 4.8 manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED

It is very popular and notice there is no 37 in their expression, they use a more advanced method to get a seed with enough entropy.

And, finally, **why is the seed an array**?  Because the standard says so.

And why is the standard designed in that way? (probably) Because there is more entropy in an array than in a single number. You have simply more combinations possible.

Comment: As an example, the Intel Fortran RANDOM_SEED size is 2. I know of some implementations that have larger seed arrays.